# How do I traverse a linked list more than once in c++?

Tags: c++, linked-list, traversal

I'm working on a homework assignment where given a linked list of n elements, m sequences are to be deleted. Each sequence has a starting value, an ending value, and a step size. However, some sequences can start at the end of the linked list and end at the beginning of the list, ex: of the list 1 2 3 4 5, I need to delete elements 5 to 2 in order (5, 1, 2).  How do I move back through the list again without looping forever?

Comment: If you iterate through the list recursively, you can "move back through the list" by returning from the current scope.

Answer (score 0):

You may do something like:

```
void remove_value_to_value_as_ring(std::list<int>& l, int val1, int val2)
{
    auto it1 = std::find(l.begin(), l.end(), val1);
    if (it1 == l.end()) {
        return; // Not found
    }
    auto it2 = std::find(it1, l.end(), val2);
    if (it2 != l.end()) {
        l.erase(it1, it2);
        return;
    }
    it2 = std::find(l.begin(), it1, val2);
    if (it2 == it1) {
        return; // Not found
    }
    l.erase(it1, l.end());
    l.erase(l.begin(), std::next(it2));
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/oVKeiX)